# Image preloading percentage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making my first Flash photogallery and when I click on thumbnail it should opet the picture in full size and display the prelaoder with percentage. It's all working offline on flash download simulator but online the percetage won't show up. It sometime start showing up around 100% or not at all.
link of the gallery: http://solarratko.netii.net/
below is some code from my class that loads the full sized images

```
public function kreni(f:String) //function that start when user click on thumbnail
    {
        URLrequest=new URLRequest(f); //URLrequest for image in full size
        dspLoader.load(URLrequest); //loading the image

        preloader.visible = true;//prelaoder that shows up is visible
        h.visible=true;//text area for percentage is visible
        dspLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progres);//adding progress event
        dspLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, kraj);//adding complete event

    }
    public function progres(e:Event):void
    {
        var perc:Number = e.target.bytesLoaded / e.target.bytesTotal;//calculatin percentage
        h.text = Math.ceil(perc*100).toString();//displaying percentage wich is not working online or it start too late

    }
    public function kraj(e:Event):void
    {
        h.text="";
        preloader.visible = false;
        h.visible=false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me.  Have you cleared your cache.  Does the preloader not show up and not load the image?

If you want to force the preloader to run, you can assign a timer to the loading sequence as a check against what's loaded.  Start the timer when you load and make sure the percentage is equal to or more than what you are displaying doing the check in the timer call back - use the progress callback to get the bytes loaded.  So the timer can be .5 sec and if the image is in cache you see a quick preloader before the image loads.

*** EDIT ***

```
public function kreni(f:String) //function that start when user click on thumbnail {

    preloader.visible = true;//prelaoder that shows up is visible
    h.visible=true;//text area for percentage is visible

    URLrequest=new URLRequest(f); //URLrequest for image in full size
    dspLoader.load(URLrequest); //loading the image

    dspLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progres);//adding progress event
    dspLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, kraj);//adding complete event

}
```

Comment: My problem is that the text that shows the percentage is not showing up. The preloader always show up but the text shows up at the end of loading image(100%).

Comment: Edited the code above - try putting the visibility of the objects to true before you call the load and see if that makes any difference

Comment: Still not working. I just noticed that the text is showing up because my mouse cursor is changing when I over it. Look's like the progress event is not triggering and still don't know why. On simulate download in flash, everything worked fine. I noticed one more thing. Sometimes, but very rare the progress event starts on time and the text is showing the percentage but usually it starts at 100% or not at all.